# Encrypted home directory not auto mounting with .profile

Tags: 12.04, encryption

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server edition with home directory encryption enabled. Logging in locally automatically decrypts and mounts my home directory and loads my zshrc. But logging in via ssh just drops me in the bare home directory without decrypting and mounting my home dir.

This is what I see

```
3014658 dr-x------ 2 david david 4096 Jan 10 14:20 .
3014657 drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Jan 10 10:22 ..
3014666 lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david   56 Jan  7 18:42 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
3014662 lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david   31 Jan  7 18:42 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/david/.ecryptfs
3014663 lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david   30 Jan  7 18:42 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/david/.Private
3015474 -rwxrwxrwx 1 david david   35 Jan 10 14:20 .profile
3014665 lrwxrwxrwx 1 david david   52 Jan  7 18:42 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
3017327 -rw------- 1 root  root   623 Jan 10 10:40 .viminfo
```

I created a ~/.profile with the permissions and ownership above. It's contents say to mount my encrypted home and cd into it to refresh my shell.

```
/usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private
cd
```

It doesn't seem to be executing on SSH login. When I run `ecryptfs-mount-private` manually, I'm prompted for a password. Perhaps this is what's preventing the automatic mounting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered:

- https://superuser.com/questions/564926/profile-is-not-loaded-when-using-ssh-ubuntu

In short, SSH don't use `~/.profile`, but it's own script `~/.ssh/rc`.